# anonymous function definition in modal.js

Tags: javascript

hey guys i was just going through the scource of modal.js and have a few questions about Javascript and also the coding convention used in the modal.js plugin ,

[Modal.js plugin](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js).

well if you see [line 76](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L76) , notice how the ananimous function starts :

```
this.backdrop(function () {
```

i am new to javascript and i have rarely seen something like that , why not just do the following :

```
(function () {
```

also where is the `this.backdrop` defined i see `this.$backdrop` defined but not
`this.backdrop` ?

secoundly , I have a question which should be relatively easy, but i just wanted to confirm to make sure , even though i ran a few tests , the question is what this points to when using prototype . look at the below skeleton code :

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // MODAL CLASS DEFINITION
  // ======================

  var Modal = function (element, options) {

    this.options  w      = options
    this.$body          = $(document.body)
    this.$element       = $(element)
    this.$backdrop      =
    this.isShown        = null
    this.scrollbarWidth = 0

    if (this.options.remote) {
      this.$element
        .find('.modal-content')
        .load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () {
          this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal')
        }, this))
    }
  }

  Modal.VERSION  = '3.3.2'

  Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION = 300
  Modal.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION = 150

  Modal.DEFAULTS = {
    backdrop: true,
    keyboard: true,
    show: true
  }

  Modal.prototype.checkScrollbar = function () {

  }

  Modal.prototype.setScrollbar = function () {

  }

  Modal.prototype.resetScrollbar = function () {

  }

  Modal.prototype.measureScrollbar = function () { 

  } 

}(jQuery);
```

what will this refer to inside say for eg. Modal.prototype.measureScrollbar ?? Modal ?? or Modal.prototype.setScrollbar also if i console.log this i get Object { options: Object, $body: Object, $element: Object, isShown: false, $backdrop: null, scrollbarWidth: 17, bodyIsOverflowing: false } but why don't i get Modal.prototype.setScrollbar , Modal.prototype.resetScrollbar ,Modal.prototype.measureScrollbar even though they are part of Modal.

Please note that my main difficulty is about the coding convention of `this.backdrop(function() { })`

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Alexander .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why...this.backdrop(function () {

Because the `backdrop` function expect a callback (see below).

> where is the this.backdrop defined i see this.$backdrop defined but not this.backdrop ?

It's defined on line 186 as part of the prototype:

```
Modal.prototype.backdrop = function
```

This means that when modals are instantiated (e.g. `new Modal`) the created objects will have a `backdrop` function on them. This is how JavaScript prototypical inheritance works. Maybe check out this article for an intro: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain